# Matching two regular expressions on each other

Tags: python, regex

I would like to compare two regular expressions in Python.

Basically, I need to test if one expression is included in the other one.

For example, is [AB]D included in [AB][CD]. or is ...K.. included in ...[KR]..

I tried something like the following but it doesn't work:

```
re.finditer(r"[AB][DF]",r"[AB]D")
re.finditer(r"[AB]D",r"[AB][CD]")
```

My expressions can have different size but a solution with same size expression would be great.

**EDIT**

All my regular expressions are prety simple.

They only contains "points", "square braquets" and "^".

. means "anything" (like * in real regexps)
  
[AB] means "A or B"
  
[^P] means "not P"

**EDIT 2**

Thanks for your answers and comments, I think I will generate the set of all string from one regexp and test them with the second regular expression.

Comment: You can find if one string is in another one with `if first_string in second_string`. Or do you mean something else when you say "is included in"?

Comment: Do you need to solve the *general* problem (any regular expressions) or simply expressions which look like yours, i.e. of the `[AB]D` vs. `[AB][CD]` variety?  The latter problem would be a *lot* simpler.

Comment: The proposed duplicate question is not stellar but the answers are.

Comment: @Kevin I mean something else: in python regexp language for example, I mean ...K.. is included in ...[KR].. or [KR] is included into [^P].

Comment: @DSM I think I want to solve general stuff but all my regular expressions are prety simple, containing "points", "square braquets" and "^". Points are the common "*" for saying anything, [AB] means A or B and [^P] means "not P".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it, but you'll have to do it yourself.  This is a lot of work and you may decide that it's not worth the effort.  Here is a way you can do it:

1. Turn the regular expressions A and B into NFAs.
2. Let *(a, b)* be the set of initial states for your two regular expressions in NFA form.
3. Take the epsilon closure of both sets, *(e(a), e(b))*.
4. For each symbol, follow all transitions from *e(a)* and *e(b)* along symbol that symbol to form a new state, *(a', b')*.
5. Go back to step three.

Eventually you will recurse over all possible sets of states for both regular expressions.  If at any point *e(b)* contains a final state but *e(a)* does not, then B is not contained in A.

This is guaranteed to terminate because there is a finite number of sets of states.  This technique will not work with backreferences.  *Technically* if you use backreferences, then they are not regular expressions any more, at least from the viewpoint of formal languages.

Comment: +1 This also requires that the expressions are *true* regular expressions, not using any of the look-ahead or look-back assertions available in the extended regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It,s way to complicated for what I want to do. In my case, I think comparing all possible expression for one regular expression will be easier. As explained in my EDIT, my regexps are very simple.